# Is there a proof of subdifferential sum rule that doesn't use duality theory?

Tags: convex-analysis

Given:

- $f$ and $g$ are lower-semicontinuous proper convex functions,
- $x \in \text{ri dom}(f) \cap \text{ri dom}(g)$,
- $h = f+g$,
- $p \in \partial h(x)$,

Prove that there exist some $s \in \partial f(x)$ and $t \in \partial g(x)$ such that $p = s+t$, without using duality theory.

I've seen this using duals, but I'm looking for a proof relying solely on the primal definitions of subdifferential
$$  s \in \partial f \;\; \Leftrightarrow \;\; f(y) \ge f(x) + s^t(y-x)  \;\; \forall \;\; y$$
and convexity
$$ f(\beta a + (1-\beta) b ) \le \beta f(a) + (1-\beta) f(b)  \;\; \forall \;\beta \in [0,1] \;\; \text{and }  a,b \in \text{dom} f$$

Comment: What do you mean by "duality theory"? The sum-rule can be understood as a separation theorem of the epigraphs of $f$ and $g$. Does such a approach satisfy "without duality theory"?

Comment: Sorry, that was an ambiguous way of wording it.  I just meant is there a direct proof using only the above two inequalities without invoking additional theorems?  It seems like there should be, but I've never seen one.
I was tinkering with it over the weekend and may have found a way.  I don't know if anyone else would care about it though...

Comment: Then you could post your proof as an answer. I feel, however, that (in infinite dimension) any proof has to use Hahn-Banach (or the AC) at some point. Hence, it is not possible by only using the inequalities.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice / feedback.  It looks like I have something that works when either f or g is continuously differentiable.  I had hoped for something less limiting, but if you're right then maybe it's a waste of time to keep looking more.  Will post it soon.  Thanks again.

Comment: @gerw could you please elaborate on your comment about the sum rule being understood as a separation theorem? (Feel free to use any duality ideas.)

Comment: @littleO: Yes, but this would be too long for a comment, I guess. Could you post a separate question?

Comment: @gerw Thank you, I just posted a separate question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310481/understanding-the-subdifferential-sum-rule