# Understanding the subdifferential sum rule

Tags: convex-analysis

A [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053642/is-there-a-proof-of-subdifferential-sum-rule-that-doesnt-use-duality-theory) asked:
Given:

- $f$ and $g$ are lower-semicontinuous proper convex functions,
- $x \in \text{ri dom}(f) \cap \text{ri dom}(g)$,
- $h = f+g$,
- $p \in \partial h(x)$,

Prove that there exist some $s \in \partial f(x)$ and $t \in \partial g(x)$ such that $p = s+t$.

In this question, it was commented that "The sum-rule can be understood as a separation theorem of the epigraphs of $f$ and $g$."  Could anyone please explain or elaborate on this comment?

More generally, could anyone explain what they think is the most enlightening way to understand the subdifferential sum rule?  Is there a point of view that makes the proof seem well-motivated or obvious?

Comment: Just one thing, your assumption for validity sum rule is so much restrictive!!  Actually  for validity of sum rule at point "x" you really don't need $x$ satisfies  the condition  $x \in \text{ri dom}(f) \cap \text{ri dom}(g)$ !  You only need find just a  $y \in \text{ri dom}(f) \cap \text{ri dom}(g)$. So condition is  $ \text{ri dom}(f) \cap \text{ri dom}(g)  \neq \emptyset $

Comment: @Redshoes Thank you for that comment, I think that's a very important point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An equivalent formulation for the sum rule is:
``find $s \in \partial f(x)$ such that $p - s \in \partial g(x)$''.

Now, we can reformulate the second relation to isolate $s$ on the left-hand side.
Define the concave function $h_p(y) = p^\top \, (y-x) - g(y) + g(x) + f(x)$. Then, the second relation becomes $s \in \hat\partial h_p(x)$, where $\hat\partial$ is the superderivative of concave functions.

Let us reconsider this sub/supergradient relation in terms of the epigraph of $f$ and the hypograph of $h_p$.
By $s \in \partial f(x)$ we obtain
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) - s^\top x \le f(y) - s^\top y
\end{equation*}
for all $y$ and this implies
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) - s^\top x \le (1, -s)^\top k
\end{equation*}
for all $k$ in the epigraph of $f$.

Similar, from $s \in \hat\partial h_p(x)$ we get
\begin{equation*}
 h_p(x) - s^\top x
 =
 f(x) - s^\top x
 \ge
 h_p(y) - s^\top y
\end{equation*}
for all $y$ and this implies
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) - s^\top x
 \ge
 (1,-s)^\top k
\end{equation*}
for all $k$ in the hypograph $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n : a \le h_p(b)\}$ of $h_p$.

Hence, the validity of the sum rule implies that we can separate the epigraph of $f$
and the hypograph of $h_p$ (which is just the mirrored, shifted and tilted epigraph of $g$).

To the contrary, 
let $p \in \partial (f+g)(x)$ be given.
This implies that the epigraph of $f$ and the hypograph of $h_p$ are disjunct.
If you can separate the epigraph of $f$ and the hypograph of $h_p$,
then you find $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(\lambda,-s) \in (\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n) \setminus \{0\}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 (\lambda,- s)^\top k \ge a \ge (\lambda,-s)^\top l
\end{equation*}
for $k$ in the epigraph of $f$ and $l$ in the epigraph of $h_p$.
Since you can make the first component of $k$ arbitrarily large, you obtain $\lambda \ge 0$,
and $\lambda = 0$ cannot happen, since this would imply $s = 0$.
Hence, we can rescale $\lambda$ to be $1$.
This implies
\begin{equation*}
 f(y) - s^\top y \ge a \ge (p^\top \, (y-x) - g(y) + g(x) + f(x)) - s^\top y
\end{equation*}
for all $y$.
Plugging in $y = x$ yields $a = f(x) - s^\top x$.
The considerations above yield $s \in \partial f(x)$ and $p - s \in \partial g(x)$.

I hope this answer clarifies that a sum rule is essentialy a separation theorem.

Comment: The one thing that is confusing me is the first line "find $s\in\partial f(x) $ such that $p−s\in\partial g(x)$". I think it should be "for all $s\in \partial f(x)$, prove $p-s\in \partial g(x)$", which is the part of the sum rule that is hard to prove. ?

Comment: One example is when $ f (x) = \max (-x,0) $ and $ g (x) = \max (x, 0) $. So $ h (x) = |x|$. Then $ p = 1 \in \partial h (0)$ and $ s = -1 \in \partial f (0) $, but $ p - s=2$ is not in $\partial g (0) $.

Comment: Hmm, I see! Yeah minkowski sum is a tricky business...

Comment: @gerw, how do you conclude s=0 when $\lambda$=0?  If we think of $k=(t,y),l=(t',y')$, we can't have $y,y' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ arbitrary.  So how do we know we don't have $d_1 \perp Dom(f) \cap Dom(g)$?  Thx for your consideration.

Comment: @Jason, you are right, it might happen that $s \in (\mathrm{dom}(f))^\perp \cap (\mathrm{dom}(g))^\perp$. We can circumvent this situation if we work in the affine hull of $\mathrm{dom}(f) \cap \mathrm{dom}(g)$.