# Subgradient of a composition w/ affine $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ be convex, w/ subgradient at x in its domain $\partial f(x):=\{ d:f(y)\geq f(x)+d^T (y-x),\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n \}$. 
Let $h(x'):=f(Ax'+b)$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, then its subgradient is $$\partial h(x')=A^T \partial f(Ax'+b) $$  (So I googled for this result, but I'd like to convince myself it's true) 
I think I can see "$\supseteq$", but I'm having trouble w/ "$\subseteq$" b/c 
by defn $$\partial h(x')=\{ d' \in \mathbb{R}^m : f(Ay'+b) \geq f(Ax'+b)+d'^T(y'-x'), \forall y' \in \mathbb{R}^m \}$$ while $$A^T \partial f(Ax'+b)=\{ A^T d:f(y) \geq f(Ax'+b)+d^T (y-Ax'-b),\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$$  Another approach I tried is to let $d' \in \partial h(x')$ but assume 
either $d' \notin Range(A^T)$ or $d'=A^T d$ for some $d \notin \partial f(Ax+b)$.  Either assumption should lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have another answer, which is in the spirit of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1310604/58577

For ease of notation, I use $b = 0$. The shift with $b \ne 0$ does not cause any difficulties.

Let $d' \in \partial h(x')$ be given.
We define the sets
\begin{align*}
 A &= \{(s, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n ; s < f(A \, x') - f(y)\} \\
 B &= \{(s, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n ; \exists y' \in \mathbb{R}^m : A \, y' = y,\; \text{and}\; s > -d'^\top (y' - x').\}
\end{align*}
Note that $A$ is the shifted, strict hypograph of $f$,
whereas $B$ is the preimage of the strict epigraph of $d'^\top( \cdot - x')$.

It is easy to see that these two sets are disjoint and $A$ is open.
Hence, we can use a separation theorem to get
$(t, -d) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$, $(t,-d) \ne 0$, and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, such that
\begin{equation*}
 (t, -d)^\top (s,y)
 \ge
 a
 \ge
 (t, -d)^\top (\tilde s,\tilde y)
\end{equation*}
for all $(s,y) \in B$ and $(\tilde s, \tilde y) \in A$.
It is easy to see that $t > 0$ and w.l.o.g. we have $t = 1$.

By using $y = \tilde y = A \, x'$,
$s \searrow 0$, $\tilde s \nearrow 0$, we find $a = -d^\top A \, x'$.

Now, we use arbitrary $(y, y')$,
$(\tilde s, y) \in A$, $(s, A \, y') \in B$
and $s \searrow -d'^\top (y' - x')$,
$\tilde s \nearrow f(A \, x' ) - f(y)$,
we get
\begin{equation*}
 -d'^\top (y' - x') - d^\top A \, y'
 \ge
 -d^\top A \, x'
 \ge
 f(A \, x') - f(y) - d^\top y.
\end{equation*}
The first inequality shows $A^\top d = d'$
and the second one $d \in \partial f(A x')$.

Comment: Thx.  Some remaining questions: a) how do you know $t>0$?  b) why do you need that A is open?  It seems to use separation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), you only need to know $A,B$ are convex and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: Let me show how $t>0$ follows. Since $s$ can be made as big as possible due to the definition of $B$, $t<0$ cannot happen. And the case $t = 0$ can be excluded, since in this case, we could choose arbitrary $y$, which would result in $d = 0$, but $(t,-d) \ne $. $A$ open is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer which uses that
$$f'(x; y) = \max_{d \in \partial f(x)}y^\top d,$$
where $f'(x;y)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $y$.

Let $d'$ be given, such that $d' \not\in A^\top \partial f(Ax+b)$. Since $\partial f(Ax+b)$ is compact, the set $A^\top \partial f(Ax+b)$ is compact and convex.
Hence, we can separate $d'$ and $A^\top \partial f(Ax+b)$.
That is, there is $s \in \mathbb{R}^m$, such that
$$s^\top d' > s^\top \tilde d\qquad \forall \tilde d \in A^\top \partial f(Ax+b).$$
This yields
$$s^\top d' > s^\top A^\top d\qquad \forall d \in \partial f(Ax+b).$$
Now, we invoke the formula for the directional derivative and obtain
$$\max_{\tilde d' \in \partial h(x)} s^\top \tilde d' = h'(x;s) = f'(A \, x + b; A \, s) = \max_{d \in \partial f(Ax+b)} (A\,s)^\top d < s^\top d'$$
This shows that $d' \not\in \partial h(x)$.